# AngularJS : Seqential Promise chain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Function `one` passes value to `two` and then `two` passes value to `three`. Any of these functions could take any amount of time to return data. How can I make them wait for value instead of rushing ahead and printing `undefined`.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

var one = function (msg) {
  $timeout(function () {
    console.log(msg);
    return "pass this to two";
  }, 2000);
};

var two = function (msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  return "pass this to three";
};

var three = function (msg) {
  console.log(msg);
};

deferred.promise
  .then(one)
  .then(two)
  .then(three);

deferred.resolve("pass this to one");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **`return` a promise from every function that does something asynchronous**.

In your case, your `one` function returns `undefined`, while it would need to return the promise that you created for the `"pass this to two"` value after the timeout:

```
function one (msg) {
  return $timeout(function () {
//^^^^^^
    console.log(msg);
    return "pass this to two";
  }, 2000);
}
```

Btw, instead of using `var deferred = $q.defer();`, the chain is better written as:

```
one("pass this to one")
  .then(two)
  .then(three);
```